# Warning when compiling .cu with -Wpedantic: "style of line directive is a GCC extension"

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, cuda

I'm collaborating on an opensource project where the global compiler settings include `-Werror` and `-pedantic`, so in order to have my contributions accepted, I'll have to comply with those.

Second, I'm a Windows person, so I have happily built a new component of this project, only to realize now that it doesn't compile on Linux, throwing the following warning:

```
style of line directive is a GCC extension
```

on every single line (on every 3rd char to be specific) of a CUDA (.cu) source file that is part of my component.

I'm using cmake with the `FindCUDA.cmake` scripts to compile CUDA. The source file doesn't contain any `#line` directive so I'm completely clueless as to what GCC is complaining about.

First I thought it was line-endings, but the Linux "file" command reports the `.cu` file as "C source, ASCII text", no "with CRLF line terminators".

The rest of the opensource project doesn't contain any CUDA, so I have nothing to compare with.

What does this warning mean exactly, and how do I get rid of it?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16519008/why-followed-by-a-number-seems-do-nothing-in-c-plus-plus

Answer (score 8):

I think what is happening is that nvcc is generating C source from your `.cu` source files for gcc to consume, and in so doing it is including gcc-style line directives of the form `#1234`. By compiling this intermediate C code with `gcc -pedantic` you then get a problem because these are gcc-style line directives and are non-standard. The solution is to not use `-pedantic`, at least for the CUDA part of the project.

Comment: Thanks. Had to disable all nvcc warnings using --disable-warnings flag because I could not figure out how temporairly disable -pedantic (using #pragma GCC diagnostic didn't do much). Now down to a bunch of [warning: command line option -std=c++11’ is valid for C++/ObjC++ but not for C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26867352/cant-get-rid-of-warning-command-line-option-std-c11-using-nvcc-cuda-cma) warnings...

Comment: @Genoil,  `-Wno-pedantic` (modulo https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50955666/wno-pedantic-ignored-on-older-gcc)