# -Wno-pedantic ignored on older gcc

Tags: c++, gcc, meson-build, gcc-pedantic

I have a C++ application where I am using zero-arguments-variadic macros. However, I don't really like the standard conforming solution posted here on SO in various answers, but rather keep the GCC specific `##__VAR_ARGS__`.

I'd like to catch as much warnings as possible though.

My build system is meson and I passed the options `--buildtype=debugoptimized --warning_level=2 --werror=true` and specify `-Wno-pedantic` as an addtional project argument.

Ob Ubuntu 18.04, gcc 7.3.0, meson 0.45.1 this adds the following options to the compiler: `-Wall -Wextra -Werror -Wpedantic -Wno-pedantic -std=c++11` and everything builds fine.

The same code, the same options on CentOS 7.4.1708, gcc 4.8.5, meson 0.44.1 adds extactly the same options to the compiler but does not compile and I get the following error:

`ISO C99 requires rest arguments to be used` (for the variadic macros)

It seems that `-Wno-pedantic` is ignored in this compiler.

I can play around with the warning options a bit, but either on Ubuntu or CentOS the build is failing. When the Ubuntu build fails, the error message is a bit different:

`ISO C++11 requires at least one argument for the "..." in a variadic macro`

The only solution to make both builds succeed I found so far is using `meson --buildtype=plain --warning_level=1 -werror=true` and setting `-Wall -Wextra` as project arguments.

So I'm not sure if this is a compiler issue, a meson issue or just some unfortunate version difference I'm hitting.

Comment: You could dodge all this mess and conditionally set flags depending on the gcc version

Comment: Have you tried std=gnu++11?

Comment: @bolov I don't want to work around the issue but fix it. I consider adding version checks a dirty hack which gets even dirtier when other compilers (clang) and other targets come into play.